# Displaying an Image with Matplotlib in deeplearning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Running this piece of code:

```
#loading test images
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
test_path,image_size=(img_height,img_width), label_mode='int', 
batch_size=batch_size)
                                                       
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
for img ,label in val_ds.take(1):
    for i in range(12):
        ax = plt.subplot(4,3,i + 1)
        plt.imshow(img[i].numpy().astype('uint8'))
        plt.title(class_name[label[i]])
        plt.axis('off')
```

I got this error :

> NotFoundError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: D:\Machine
> Learning\DPL\Deep Learning for Computer Vision with TensorFlow
> 2[TutsNode.com] - Deep Learning for Computer Vision with TensorFlow
> 2\3. Convolutional Neural Networks\15.1
> covid19\covid19\test\Covid\auntminnie-a-2020_01_28_23_51_6665_2020_01_28_Vietnam_coronavirus.jpeg
> : The system cannot find the path specified. ; No such process
> [[{{node ReadFile}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]

Any help ??

Answer (score 0):

As per official documentation

image_dataset_from_directory function:

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
directory,
labels="inferred",
label_mode="int",
class_names=None,
color_mode="rgb",
batch_size=32,
image_size=(256, 256),
shuffle=True,
seed=None,
validation_split=None,
subset=None,
interpolation="bilinear",
follow_links=False,
crop_to_aspect_ratio=False,
**kwargs
)
```

there is no argument like test_path but you mention this in your code.

And for loading image you have to use this function:

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
path, grayscale=False, color_mode="rgb", target_size=None, 
interpolation="nearest"
)
```